# Can I use macro extension tubes with telephoto lenses?

Tags: canon, extension-tubes

What I really want is an extension tube for my telephoto lens. (70-200mm Canon) I have an opportunity to purchase a number of macro tubes. Will those also work with the telephoto lens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, they'll work - tubes should work* with any lens, even a reversed one for *extreme* macro.

**But** the magnification is relative to the focal length - so adding 50mm of extension tubes to 200mm doesn't get you super close, show stopping macro shots.  Using it at the 70mm end will produce higher magnification shots (although probably not 1:1), but less working distance.

Also, check out [How can I estimate the reproduction ratio of an unknown macro setup?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13228/how-can-i-estimate-the-reproduction-ratio-of-an-unknown-macro-setup) and [How can I calculate the change an extension tube makes to the maximum magnification of a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9888/how-can-i-calculate-the-change-an-extension-tube-makes-to-the-maximum-magnficatio)

*<sub>Obviously if they don't have electrical contacts you'll lose a lot of auto stuff, but that's not relevant to the focal length issue.</sub>

Comment: Great. Thanks. The guy is selling a whole bunch for real cheap so I will play around with them.

Comment: @Jakub - You can get simple tubes wicked cheap on Amazon, so *caveat emptor*. http://www.amazon.com/Fotodiox-Extension-Extreme-Close-up-Digital/dp/B003Y60DZO

Comment: Though if you are reversing the lens a wide-angle is better.

Comment: @Elendil - You could theoretically stack a wide angle on a super telephoto and put extension tubes on that for upwards of 20:1 +

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago, I used tubes with my Canon 135/2.8 to get a shot I couldn't get with anything else in my bag, including a 50/1.4 which is theoretically "better" to use with tubes.

The shortest tube I had on the 50 compressed DoF so much and reduced the far focus distance so much that I simply couldn't get the shot. The subject was too big to fit in the frame once it was in focus, and I would have had to close down the aperture too much for the available light. (Raising ISO wasn't an option here.)

All I really needed for this shot is to reduce the near focus limit a bit so I could get a little closer than the lens would allow on its own.

So, yes. Tubes FTW.